# Why isPrototypeOf returning false, yet I can go up the prototype chain?

Tags: javascript

Maybe my understanding of prototype inheritance is off.  Its interesting that I am inheriting from my object, but still returns false.  Sorry if this is a dumb question to those that are going to thumbs down me.

Yes, I purposely spelled out my variables and or objects for demonstration purposes and yes I purposely am attempting to use .create as oppose to new ().

```
var VehiclePrototype = {
   type: "car"
};

var carPrototype = Object.create(VehiclePrototype);

carPrototype.wheels = null;
carPrototype.make = null;
carPrototype.model = null;

var jamesCar = Object.create(carPrototype);

var x = jamesCar.type
alert(x);

alert(Object.isPrototypeOf(jamesCar, VehiclePrototype));  //false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling the function improperly. Try:

```
alert(VehiclePrototype.isPrototypeOf(jamesCar));
```

The `.isPrototypeOf()` function is on the Object **prototype** — that means it's callable as a method from any object. You call it as a method on the object that you want to test to see whether it's a prototype of some other object. (The other object is the parameter.)

Note that your code wasn't an error because it wasn't really *wrong*, at least in JavaScript terms. Your call was asking whether the Object constructor was a prototype of the "jamesCar" object, which it clearly wasn't.

Comment: Oh, thanks.  So it was inheriting right, I just called it wrong.

Comment: @dragonore yes exactly :)

Comment: [Mozilla Documentation isProtoTypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isPrototypeOf)